# Euler characteristic of local system depends only on rank?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, etale-cohomology, euler-characteristics

Let $X$ be a proper variety over a finite field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$, and let $\mathcal F$ be a finite rank $\mathbb F_\ell$ local system on (the etale site of) $X$.  Is it true (and, if so, how does one prove) that
$$\chi(X,\mathcal F)=\operatorname{rk}\mathcal F\cdot\chi(X,\underline{\mathbb F_\ell}_X)$$
where $\underline{\mathbb F_\ell}_X$ denotes the constant local system on $X$?

Some remarks:

- If $k=\mathbb C$, then this is true (without assuming properness), but the only proof I know is via analytification and topological arguments.  This implies the result for $(X,\mathcal F)$ which lift to characteristic zero, but this leaves out lots of varieties $X$ and local systems $\mathcal F$.
- Properness is necessary when $\operatorname{char}k>0$.  Namely, let $f:\mathbb A^1\to\mathbb A^1$ denote the Artin--Schrier map over $\mathbb F_p$, so $f_\ast\underline{\mathbb F_\ell}_{\mathbb A^1}$ is a local system since $f$ is etale.  Now $\operatorname{rk}f_\ast\underline{\mathbb F_\ell}_{\mathbb A^1}=p$, but $\chi(\mathbb A^1,f_\ast\underline{\mathbb F_\ell}_{\mathbb A^1})=\chi(\mathbb A^1,\underline{\mathbb F_\ell}_{\mathbb A^1})$ by the Leray spectral sequence.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/135983/status-of-the-euler-characteristic-in-characteristic-p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $X$ is proper, the Swan conductor of $\mathcal{F}$ vanishes. Hence the identity $\chi(X,\mathcal F)=\operatorname{rk}\mathcal F\cdot\chi(X,\underline{\mathbb F_\ell}_X)$ follows from Theorem $4.2.9$ in Kato & Saito's ["Ramification theory for varieties over a perfect field
".](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0402010)

Comment: Thanks!  As stated, the theorem you cite only applies when $X$ is smooth.  Any idea whether the methods would generalize to the non-smooth case?

Comment: Kato--Saito cites Illusie in the proof of Theorem 4.2.9.  Reading the MR review, it would seem that the answer to my question is actually due to Illusie: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=629127

Comment: @JohnPardon If I recall correctly the argument of that paper is essentially due to Deligne but was written up by Illusie. However even the result of Deligne and Illusie is more general than the situation requires. This follows immediately from the Lefschetz fixed point formula of SGA applied to a finite etale cover on which the bundle trivializes. The Euler characteristic may be computed as a sum of traces of the automorphisms of the bundle. The nontrivial automorphisms have no fixed points, so no contribution, and the contribution of the trivial automorphism depends only on the rank.

Comment: @WillSawin Great, just let me ask a stupid question: at which point in that argument is properness used?

Comment: @JohnPardon The Lefschetz fixed point formula requires the variety to be proper.

Comment: @WillSawin, can you elaborate on your last two sentences? What is the trace formula expressing euler characteristic of a local system as sum of traces of automorphisms?

Comment: @user84144 One views the cohomology of a local system coming from a representation $\pi$ of a finite quotient $G$ of the fundamental group as the space of homomorphisms from $\pi^\vee$ to the cohomology of the corresponding $G$-cover. Then apply character theory to calculate the dimension of this in terms of traces of automorphisms. I guess one has to compare the mod-$\ell$ Homs to some $\ell$-adic Homs and use character theory there. This is all in the paper of Illusie, it's just that there is a bunch of additional stuff in that paper to gable ramification that is not needed here.